# What is sent to the program when the user presses enter in the console?

Tags: c, console

Edit: DanielFischer pointed out the problem with the code below, in case anyone is curious.

If the user enters a formatted string and presses enter what exactly is sent to the program reading it?

```
Enter name> John Smith
```

Does this send null terminated strings only or is there a signifying character saying they hit enter as well?

Edit: I thought what Mike says would be true. But then why does this snippet of code not work?

```
printf( "Enter command> " );
memset( buf, 0, BUFSIZ );
do{
    temp = getchar();
    if{ temp != '\n' ) strcat( buf, &temp );
}while( temp != '\n' );
strcat( buf, "\0" );
```

Comment: What function are you using to read the input?

Comment: @EricFinn Let's say getchar().

Comment: `strcat` needs a pointer to the first `char` in a 0-terminated `char` array. `&temp` isn't one.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. Thank was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is sent to the terminal is 10 characters:

```
[J][o][h][n][ ][S][m][i][t][h][\n]
```

How the program handles it, depends on the function being used to read the input. The final character there (`'\n'`) is the indication that we hit "enter".

A null terminated string is a concept internal to the program (ie string functions required it to work properly), you won't see a NULL terminator coming from `stdin` in your example.

This is why you need to understand how the functions work that accept data from the user, if it takes the newline character, you may need to strip it. If it doesn't automatically append a null terminator, you should probably add one, etc.

Comment: I thought that that was what would be coming through. I updated the OP to show the little bit of code that does not seem to be working.

Comment: @user1362058 - [strcat()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) concatenates two strings, [getchar()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) returns an int. So you're `strcat()` a `char*` and the address of an `int`... that's not going to work. Even if that was OK `getchar()` will only take 1 letter at a time... Check my last paragraph, you need to know how these functions work, what they expect as input and what they give as output.

Comment: Thank you Mike. I have been using cplusplus.com to try and understand the library functions, but they only give one example and most of the time they are very basic.

Comment: @user1362058 - yes, also keep in mind that a lot of the examples on cplusplus.com are flawed, so they can't always be trusted. The man pages (type: `man strcat` into google for example) are very good for correct usage. Once you know the inputs and outputs of the functions just do a few web searches for "strcat example code C" or something to that effect